# finding out the chord length

Tags: geometry

[image]
Let there are given that. Radius of the circle is 2 and CD= 1.5 = CB .
Now how to find out the arc length of CD or CB?

In this case we know the all length but not any angle.

**EDIT:Calculator is not allowed.**

Comment: Please share your thoughts so far :)

Comment: 1. Calculate the angle $CAB$. 2. Calculate the circumference of the circle. 3. Multiply the circumference by the angle and divide the result by 360.

Comment: I had the problem in finding the angle. Which law will I use?

Comment: HINT: The triangle there is $2$ by $2$ by $1.5$.

Comment: Cosine rule! $CB^2=CA^2+AB^2 -2CA.AB.cos(CAB)$

Comment: @NickyHekster: Change the "backslash dot" to "backslash cdot".

Comment: if I am not allowed to use the calculator then it will be hard to evaluate this. Is there any alternative?

Comment: @ComplexGuy: If you're not allowed to use the calculator then you should mention that in the question.

Comment: @TomCollinge  We are not know any of the angle you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Draw the perpendicular bisector AP of DC.

[image]

For some reasons, the two marked angles are equal to θ.

Thus, CD = 2*DQ = 2*r sin θ

∴ sin θ = … = 3 / 8

From which, θ is known.

∴ Arc DC = 0.5*(arc DB) = 0.5 r*(4θ)

Finding θ, without using calculator, is almost impossible.

A rough approximation:-

θ is roughly 22 degrees. 4θ is roughly 90 degrees.

Then, arc CD is roughly one-eighth of the circumference [or 2π(2) / 4) / 2].

Answer (score 1):

Add the line *AC* and for brevity label the angles $C\hat AB = A, A\hat B C = B, B\hat C A = C$. Then triangle ABC is isosceles and $C = B = 1/2(\pi - A) = \pi / 2 - A/2$. Now use the sine rule so that $CB / sin (A) = AB / sin(B)$ gives $1.5/sin(A) = 2/ sin (\pi / 2 - A/2)$. Note that for any angle *X* we have $sin(\pi/2 - X) = cos (X)$, so

$1.5 cos (A/2) = 2 sin(A)$. Expand $sin(A) = 2sin(A/2)cos(A/2)$ and then

$1.5 cos(A/2) = 4sin(A/2)cos(A/2)$, and $sin (A/2) = 3/8$ ( $A/2 = 0.384396774$ rad with calculator)

S0 $A = 2sin^{-1} (3/8)$ and the arc length, $CB  = 2\pi .2 (A/2\pi) = 2.A = 4sin^{-1} (3/8)$

Without a calculator this is difficult to get a numeric answer, with one you can get an approximation of 1.537

Answer (score 0):

Consider the triangle CDA.

We know the length AC as it is also a radius of the circle.

Thus, we know the length of all three sides so we can find angle CAD with the cos rule.

Let angle CAD = $\theta$ and the lengths CD, AD and AC = a, b and c respectively.

$$\cos(\theta)=\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}$$
$$\cos(\theta)=\frac{2^2+2^2-1.5^2}{2\times2\times2}$$
$$\therefore \quad \cos(\theta)=\frac{23}{32}$$
$$\theta =\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{23}{32}\right) \approx 0.769$$

We can find that angle CAB will be the same value with the same method (or by noting that the triangle is symmetrical).

By using the formula for arc length, $l=r\theta$ we can find the arc CD.

$$\therefore CD=CB=2\cos^{-1}\left(-\frac{23}{32}\right)\approx 1.54$$

I don't see how you could find an approximate answer without a calculator though.

Comment: Pls check your cosine formula.

Comment: cheers for noticing (I'd stupidly changed it from the correct answer to that)